# How to query Link table based data in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Table 1: **Student**

`StudentID, StudentName`

Table 2: **Course**

`CourseID, CourseName`

Table 3: **Group**

`GroupID, GroupName`

Table 4: **StudentCourseGroup**

`StudentID, CourseID, GroupID`

I want all the students who belongs to 'xyz' course in following format

```
Class MyStudent

    string StudentName
    String [] Groups
```

Each student can be member of one or more groups and I need to populate "Class MyClass" in my LINQ query so that it holds `StudentName` and List of Groups in each object.

Can you please suggest a LINQ query that can do so.

Comment: Can you show us [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: var query = from S in db.Students 
 join scg in db.StudentCourseGroup on S.StudentID equal scg .StudentId
 join C in db.Courses on SCG.CourseId equals C.CourseId
                        join G in db.Groups on SCG.GROUPID equals G.GROUPID
                        select new UserDetails()
                                                      {
                                                          FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                                          GROUPS={here is need list of Groups}
};

Comment: The problem with this query is it returns two separate rows in case student is the memeber of two groups. What i want is a Student object with Nested string[] object for Groups in each Student Object

Comment: @user1711287 have you tried my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from s in db.Student
            join scg in db.StudentCourseGroup on s.StudentID equals scg.StudentID
            join c in db.Course on scg.CourseID equals c.CourseID
            join g in db.Group on scg.GroupID equals g.GroupID
            where c.CourseName == "xyz"
            select new { s, g } into x
            group x by x.s into studentGroups
            select new MyStudent {
                StudentName = studentGroups.Key.StudentName,
                Groups = studentGroups.Select(sg => sg.g.GroupName)
            };
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks alright but it throws exception on Groups = studentGroups.Select(sg => sg.g.GroupName).ToArray(), it says LINQ does not recognize LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] ToArray[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method

Comment: @user1711287 well, you can change MyStudent groups property type to `IEnumerable<string> Groups` and simply remove `ToArray()`. Or you should move `MyStudent` objects creation to memory.

Comment: Or you should move MyStudent objects creation to memory?? Can you please elaborate bit more

Comment: Error says Query should end with select , Perhaps Select is not as good as select

Comment: @user1711287 sorry, missed select statement: `(from ... group x by x.s into studentGroups select studentGroups).ToList().Select(sg => new MyStudent { ... })`

Comment: Many Thanks, How you mastered LINQ. Online tutorials are too basic. Can you please recommend me a better resource / Method to master it. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1711287 I highly recommend [pluralsight video courses](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/courses/index) there is trial access available + practice, lot of practice :)